# Automatically zoom out the whole website on Magento?

Tags: html, css, zooming

is there a way to make my website automatically zoom out to 90% ?
Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with magento, and zoom is a browser level feature. You could use CSS transforms, etc `-webkit-transform: scale(0.9)`. Terrible idea though; instead you should change your css accordingly.

Comment: cheers, i'll try that. what makes you think it's a terrible idea? thanks

Comment: Because it is. Make the CSS make stuff fit. You get weird reflows and nasty stuff happens because you have no control of how zoom works per browser. You have control wit CSS and can compare it in the popular browsers so your website actually looks like what you designed.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with css3 scale attribute but beware that this is not support on all browsers.

http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp/

```
    body{

       transform: scale(0.9);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.9); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform: scale(0.9); /* Firefox */

}
```

Or with jquery and javascript for cross browser by appending a div around the content off the site and scaling to 90% off the body width;

Something roughly like

```
var bdwidth = $("body").width();

$("wrapper").width((bdwidth / 100)*90);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS

```
body {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.9, 0.9); /* Moz-browsers */
    zoom: 0.9; /* Other non-webkit browsers */
    zoom: 90%; /* Webkit browsers */
}
```

This worked for me!